# Are server-conn and client-conn channels the only channels that could have more than one instances?

Tags: ibm-mq

I cannot figure out a way to get other channel types, e.g. sender channel, to be multiple instances.  There is nothing documented against this.  I am assuming only the connection channels could have multiple instances.  Is this correct?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Channels that can have multiple instances include channels used by clients (MQI channels) and the channels used by QMgrs (MCA channels) that are inbound types - RCVR, RQSTR and CLUSRCVR.  Outbound MCA channels (SDR, SVR, CLUSSDR) are associated with a single remote destination and must be uniquely named.

Comment: Thanks a lot, T.Rob!
I am curious about how rcvr could be in multiple instances as they are usually pair up with a single sdr.  I will pop another question on that.  Sorry for the delay in the response.